Battery Issue In Ubuntu V/S WIndows ( I have tried using auto-cpufreq) - HELP
I recently switched from Windows to Ubuntu and I see much higher battery use on Ubuntu compared to Windows. I tried to install auto cpufreq, but I think it only made a marginal difference. The estimated times vary very quickly, how can I fix this?
(I am currently using HP VICTUS laptop  with GTX 1650 TI inside)
Windows can give around 4.5hr backup with moderate usage whereas
this only does 2.5 hrs or less depending on the work done

Please [edit] your question and give us some context. First, what machine is this? You mention a battery, so should we assume some sort of laptop? Or tablet? Which one? If a laptop, tell us if you have a discrete graphics card.

Done , it's victus laptop with gtx 1650 ti

Yeah, it's almost certainly going to be the graphics card. Sadly, Windows is much better at using it only when necessary.

So isn't there any way out of this :-(

Hey @terdon , i wrote an answer for the same can you tell how is the answer ? I am a beginner in the community

Recently i started using ubuntu . As i used , i observed that my PC's battery life drains pretty fast when i used Ubuntu as compared to windows (There was a drastic difference)
So i surfed the internet and i found out that It was MY GPU which was behind this whole mess.
GPU's specially NVIDIA and linux don't go along well . You will certainly face difficulty while installing linux on laptop with dedicated GPU in it . Also In LINUX , the power management isn't as good as WINDOWS but there are certain tools which can assist you and help save your laptop.
HERE ARE FEW OF THEM
1.[Auto cpufreq] - this app is a gem , it basically toggles your cpu clock speeds etc. according to your needs
2.[envycontrol] - Disables GPU if you don't need it (very much needed)

So first i installed cpufreq  by refering[https://github.com/AdnanHodzic/auto-cpufreq]  . This app has a simple and easy to use GUI for beginners
Now i have used this app and it has increased the battery life to some extent
-> I recommend to disable your GPU also because it might keep running in the background even if you don't need it . You can enable it again depending upon your needs
for that you need to download envycontrol and you can use the CLI for that because i have spent hours trying to download the GUI for the same but it doesn't work .
You can refer [https://github.com/bayasdev/envycontrol] for instructions about how to download . I have disabled the GPU because i ain't into Gaming as such for now . Plus if i need that for future applications or gaming , i can simply enable it or download the games in windows because GPU runs better on that . I ain't saying windows is better , but i think one day such problems will be accounted for ...
(THIS IS A SELF ANSWER BTW)
hope it helps
-kav
